# Testlink create Jira issue version field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, testlink

I am integrating Jira rest into Testlink, the configuration is as below:

```
    <!-- Template jirarestInterface -->
<issuetracker>
<username>username</username>
<password>password</password>
<uribase>https://xxx.atlassian.net</uribase>
<!-- CRITIC - WITH HTTP getIssue() DOES NOT WORK -->
<uriapi>https://marocks.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/</uriapi>
<uriview>https://marocks.atlassian.net/browse/</uriview>
<userinteraction>1</userinteraction>
<!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->
<projectkey>IS</projectkey>
<issuetype>10202</issuetype>
<issuepriority>2</issuepriority>
</issuetracker>
```

However, i came accross a problem, when i create an issue it ask me the Version:

[image]

it seems to be a select type, where is it coming from ?

Do i forgot something in the configuration file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This version field is empty because you have not specified any version for your project in JIRA. In my case it was Fix version in JIRA. Currently the rest API is getting an empty list of versions. You can try

> `curl -X GET https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/IS/versions
>   -H 'authorization: Basic dtgzkisVlbyhsuYWhtYijdsdidjjsidDkw'`

This will give you an empty list.
Once you set FixVersion for your project in JIRA, this API will return the list of available versions for your project and the Version field will be populated with those versions.

PS: use your own authorization headers. You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for this purpose.